# Why Java variable cannot be resolved in ForEach Statement? " error comes in my JSP's as it cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: java, jsp, exception

I get following error in my JSP. Not sure why the **shipmentDate** cannot be identified.

> JSPException: shipmentDate cannot be resolved to a variable

```
                <tr>
                <%      Map<String, Object> shipmentDates = (Map)bookingRequestPDFContentProvider.getPdfValues().get("SHIPMENTDATES"); %>
                <%      Map<String, Object> shipmentDatesWithTime = (Map)bookingRequestPDFContentProvider.getPdfValues().get("SHIPMENTDATESINTZ"); %>
                <%      Set<String> set = shipmentDates.keySet(); %>
                <% for( String shipmentDate : set) { %>
                
                    <td align="left" colspan="2" class="tableCellBottomBorder">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                            <% if(shipmentDatesWithTime.containsKey(shipmentDate)  && shipmentDatesWithTime.get(shipmentDate) != null ) { %>
                                <td class='label'><% shipmentDates.get(shipmentDate); %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class='data'> <% shipmentDatesWithTime.get(shipmentDate); %>  </td>
                                <% } %>
                            </tr>
                            
                        </table>
                    </td>
                <%} %>
                </tr>
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What version of JSP? And why are you using scriptlets in 2021?

Comment: I am forced to use it since I am working in this company :D its java 8

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm working at Infor Nexus, having heavy legacy code base

Comment: You told me a version of Java. Not of JSP or the container. If it's legacy enough it might predate the `for-each` loop.

Comment: Try `Map<String, Object> shipmentDates = (Map<String, Object>)bookingRequestPDFContentProvider.getPdfValues().get("SHIPMENTDATES");`

Comment: @ThisIsntSparta yeah I am gonna try this. lets see if the JSP side do casting correctly

Comment: Map<String, Object> shipmentDates = (Map<String, Object>)bookingRequestPDFContentProvider.getPdfValues().get("SHIPMENTDATES"); this didn't work

Comment: Can we see your `bookingRequestPDFContentProvider` class, and `getPdfValues()` method? You can edit your post and add it there if you can.